# Morse code program i just need a little bit of guide with neatness

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

this is my code for making typing out Morse code

```
def main ():

    morse_code = {"a":".-","b":"-...","c":"-.-.","d":"-..","e":".","f":"..-.","g":"--.","h":"....","i":"..","j":".---","k":"-.-","l":".-..",
                  "m":"--","n":"-.","o":"---","p":".--.","q":"--.-","r":".-.","s":"...","t":"-","u":"..-","v":"...-","w":".--","x":"-..-","y":"-.--","z":"--.."}

    phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")
    print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
    for key in phrase:
        if not key.isdigit():
            print(morse_code[key], end = " ")


retry()

def retry ():
    main ()
```

When the program restarts it starts on the same line the type Morse code is at, and i don't know where to put a error print, so that if someone types a number it says try again or error before restarting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:-

```
def main():
    morse_code = {"a":".-","b":"-...","c":"-.-.","d":"-..","e":".","f":"..-.","g":"--.","h":"....","i":"..","j":".---","k":"-.-","l":".-..",
                "m":"--","n":"-.","o":"---","p":".--.","q":"--.-","r":".-.","s":"...","t":"-","u":"..-","v":"...-","w":".--","x":"-..-","y":"-.--","z":"--.."}

    phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")

    if any(char.isdigit() for char in phrase):
        print("try again")
    else:
        print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ", end = '')
        code = ' '.join(morse_code[key] for key in phrase)
        print(code)


def retry():
    main()
retry()
```

Comment: Let me know if it works for you

Comment: The OP's code allows for multiple lines of input. However, it does so via recursive calls. You should show how to allow encoding multiple lines through normal looping rather than recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably refactor to and use functions to get input from the user, then to translate the message to morse:

```
def get_message():
    while True:
        message = input("please enter your word or words: ")
        message = message.lower()
        for c in message:
            if c not in alphabet:
                print("please enter a message using the correct alphabet")
                break
        else:
            return message

def translate(message):
    code = []
    for c in message:
        code.append(morse[c])
    return ' '.join(code)

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrtsuvwxyz '
morse = {"a":".-","b":"-...","c":"-.-.","d":"-..","e":".","f":"..-.","g":"--.","h":"....","i":"..","j":".---","k":"-.-","l":".-..",
              "m":"--","n":"-.","o":"---","p":".--.","q":"--.-","r":".-.","s":"...","t":"-","u":"..-","v":"...-","w":".--","x":"-..-","y":"-.--","z":"--.."}

print(translate(get_message()))
```

Comment: ok, you seem to know more than I do. Thanks